# Opposing condition for a div

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I need to make a ball grow until it reaches 400, which thereafter it would shrink the same way. Would really appreciate feedback what I'm doing wrong in my code:

```js
var 
  ball1Size     = 100
, ball2Size     = 100
, ball2SizeStep = 50
 ;

function onBall2Click() 
  {
  var ball2 = document.querySelector('.ball2');
  ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;

  if (ball2Size > 400) {
    ball2Size = ball2Size - 100;
    } 
  else {
    ball2Size - 150;
    }

  ball2.innerText    = ball2Size;
  ball2.style.width  = ball2Size;
  ball2.style.height = ball2Size;
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color : black;
  text-align       : center;
  }
h1 {
  color : white;
  }
div {
  width         : 100px;
  height        : 100px;
  margin        : auto;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  transition    : 0.3s;
  line-height   : 50px;
  }
.ball2 {
  background-color : orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="ball2" onclick="onBall2Click()">
  SIZE
</div>
```

Comment: `ball2Size - 150` doesn't do anything with its resulting value. Did you mean `ball2Size -= 150` or `ball2Size = ball2Size - 150`? In any case, you define `ball2SizeStep` then never use it again. It seems more likely you want to toggle that between positive or negative based on the max/min ball sizes, then add that to the ball size.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi Dave, how do I do that? I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: You forgot to add `px` to `ball2.style.width` try this: `ball2.style.width = ball2Size + "px";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code fix and syntax fixes

here:

```js
   var ball1Size = 100;
    var ball2Size = 100;
    var ball2SizeStep = 50;

    function onBall2Click() {
        var ball2 = document.querySelector('.ball2');
        ball2Size = ball2Size + ball2SizeStep;

        if (ball2Size >= 400) {
           ball2SizeStep = -50
        } else if (ball2Size <= 50) {
            ball2SizeStep = 50
        }

        ball2.innerText = ball2Size;
        ball2.style.width = ball2Size + "px";
        ball2.style.height = ball2Size + "px";
   }
```

```css
 body {
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
    }
    
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: 0.3s;
        line-height: 50px;
        }

    .ball2 {
        background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="ball2" onclick="onBall2Click()" >
    SIZE
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, you need to make it `>= 400` because rn, it can actually go to 450, not 400!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do, increase the balls size for each click that it can be increased for, i.e., is under 400, when it reaches 400, decrease the ball size for each click until it reaches its original size. Rinse and repeat.

```js
var ball1Size = 100;
var ball2Size = 100;
var ball2SizeStep = 50;

let isBallDecreasing = false;

function onBall2Click() {
  var ball2 = document.querySelector('.ball2');

  if (ball2Size === 100) isBallDecreasing = false;

  if (ball2Size >= 400 || isBallDecreasing) {
    ball2Size -= 50;
    isBallDecreasing = true;
  } else {
    ball2Size += 50
    isBallDecreasing = false;
  }

  ball2.innerText = ball2Size;
  ball2.style.width = ball2Size;
  ball2.style.height = ball2Size
}
```

```html
<div class="ball2" onclick="onBall2Click()">
  SIZE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a boolean to track the direction can simplify it

```js
let direction = 1;
const min = 100;
const max = 400;
const step = 50;
let current = 100;

var ball = document.querySelector(".ball2");
ball.addEventListener("click", function() {

  current += direction * step;
  if (current >= max) {
    current = max;
    direction = -1;
  } else if (current <= min) {
    current = min;
    direction = 1;
  }

  updateElem();
});

function updateElem() {
  ball.textContent = current;
  ball.style.width  = current + 'px';
  ball.style.height = current + 'px';
}

updateElem();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.ball2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball ball2">
  SIZE
</div>
```

If you are going to have more than one of these you probably want to have some sort of way to keep track. Using data attributes can help out so you do not need more than one copy of the code.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".ball2").forEach(function (ball) {
   ball.addEventListener("click", function () {
     let direction = +ball.dataset.direction;
     const min = +ball.dataset.min;
     const max = +ball.dataset.max;
     const step = +ball.dataset.step;
     const current = +ball.dataset.current;
     
     let updated = current + direction * step;
     if (updated >= max) {
       updated = max;
       direction = -1;
     } else if (updated <=min) {
       updated = min;
       direction = 1;
     }
     
     updateElem();
     ball.dataset.direction = direction;
     ball.dataset.current = updated;
   });

   function updateElem() {
     const num = ball.dataset.current;
     ball.textContent = num;
     ball.style.width = num + 'px';
     ball.style.height = num + 'px';
   }

   updateElem();

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.ball2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div 
  class="ball ball2"
  data-direction="1"
  data-min="100"
  data-max="400"
  data-step="50"
  data-current="100">
  SIZE
</div>
<div 
  class="ball ball2"
  data-direction="-1"
  data-min="100"
  data-max="400"
  data-step="50"
  data-current="400">
  SIZE
</div>
<div 
  class="ball ball2"
  data-direction="1"
  data-min="0"
  data-max="1000"
  data-step="100"
  data-current="200">
  SIZE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also [Use CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for simplifying your code:

```js
const ball2 = document.querySelector('.ball2');
var 
  ballSz        = 100
, ball2SizeStep = 50
  ;
ball2.onclick =()=>
  {
  ballSz           += ball2SizeStep
  ball2.textContent = ballSz
  ball2.style.setProperty('--szHW', ballSz + 'px')

  if (ballSz >= 400) ball2SizeStep = -50
  if (ballSz <= 100) ball2SizeStep = +50
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color : black;
  text-align       : center;
  }
h1 {
  color : white;
  }
div {
  --szHW    : 100px;    /* <--- CSS custom properties */
  width         : var(--szHW);
  height        : var(--szHW);
  margin        : auto;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  transition    : 0.3s;
  line-height   : 50px;
  }
.ball2 {
  background-color : orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="ball2">
  SIZE
</div>
```

> the same, for multiples balls

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ball2').forEach( ball2 =>
  {
  ball2.style.setProperty('--szHW', ball2.dataset.size + 'px') // init sizes according to data-size value

  ball2.onclick =_=>
    {
    let
      min  = Number(ball2.dataset.min)
    , max  = Number(ball2.dataset.max)
    , step = Number(ball2.dataset.step)
    , size = Number(ball2.dataset.size)
      ;
    if ( size === min && step < 0
      || size === max && step > 0 )
      {
      step *= -1
      ball2.dataset.step = step
      }
    ball2.dataset.size = size += step
    ball2.style.setProperty('--szHW', size + 'px')
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  background-color : black;
  text-align       : center;
  }
div.ball2 {
  --szHW        : 100px;    /* <--- CSS custom properties */
  width         : var(--szHW);
  height        : var(--szHW);
  margin        : auto;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  transition    : 0.3s;
  line-height   : 50px;
  background    : orange;
  }
div.ball2::before {
  content: attr(data-size)
  }
```

```html
<div class="ball2" data-min="100" data-max="400"  data-step="50"  data-size="100"></div>
<div class="ball2" data-min="100" data-max="400"  data-step="50"  data-size="400"></div>
<div class="ball2" data-min="100" data-max="1000" data-step="100" data-size="200"></div>
```